How to add personal lines to a language syntax?
Id like to differentiate visually (via my personal theme) a few keywords in some languages, where the common syntax files clump in the same group.
For example, global in php.syntax. If I change the color for this I must change for all other keywords. But I also do not want to change my .vim/syntax/php.vim because I like to keep my vim files up to date automatically from "upstream".
I tried adding syn keyword ... lines to my .vimrc and even to my .vim/color/mytheme.vim (that's the only file i don't care about modifying), but it's always overriden by the syntax file (maybe because of the autofiletype stuff?)
I also tried adding the override in .vim/after/syntax/php.vim but it doesn't seem to get picked up.
I ask you smart people, who know more about the order those files are applied, where is the correct place to "append" to a syntax file?

Nothing in .vim is impacted when you update Vim, so .vim/syntax/php.vim is the right place for your custom syntax rules.

Much smarter people have already written :help startup which explains exactly what happens in which order.

@romainl thanks romain. I do carry a profile across systems and keep my .vim/{syntax/plugin/...} as if it were my platform files, so i don't depend on the system having the latest vim share files. it's odd, but i known many people who do the same.

@Friedrich no mention of syntax on help startup :( also i assume loading filetypes late might override what happens on startup, right?

Syntax files are config files. They just happen to concern themselves with syntax. But yes, :help .vimrc (below :help startup) is rather brief. You'd have to combine it with :help runtimepath to get a complete picture.

Overriding this via .vim/after/syntax/php.vim works and you can check that via :scriptnames.
The problem you seem to be running into is that keywords such as global are only recognized when contained within other specific syntax block. Luckily, there's a syntax cluster named phpClFunction that you can extend with your own keyword.
The following contents inside .vim/after/syntax/php.vim will highlight the keyword global into a different group:
syntax keyword phpGlobal global
syntax cluster phpClFunction add=phpGlobal
hi def link phpGlobal Title

I used the Title highlight group, but you can change that to something else you prefer.

always forget about :scriptnames! thanks for even reading my mind for the full solution, which works perfectly for all the syntax files i needed.
